# What does it mean when something interests you

Tags: american-english

I just wanted to know because I am curious and I just wanted to know because I see this statement online everyday

Comment: Have you looked it up in a dictionary yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it interests you, you want to learn more about it. For example, "The fact that bears can run at 56 kilometers an hour interests me. Do you know anything about it?" Does this make sense?

-Mikey (Native English Speaker)

Answer (score -1):

If something interests you,you want to know more about it or do it ,it is like you are interested in something or interested in doing something like for example "going to the beach interests me" that means I want to go to the beach ,another example would be philosophy interests me that means I want to learn more about philosophy.